# using single-spa-angular when i build the project my less transfer to js not css

Tags: angular, webpack, ng-zorro-antd, single-spa-angular

i have angular project is child app using with single-spa-angular
using UI library ng zorro
and when i build the project with custom webpack my less will transfer js
but i need transfer to css

the angular version 15
my angular.json setting

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less",
              {
                "input": "src/styles/light.less",
                "bundleName": "light",
                "inject": false
              },
              {
                "input": "src/styles/dark.less",
                "bundleName": "dark",
                "inject": false
              }
            ],
"customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "extra-webpack.config.js",
              "libraryName": "zorrothemetest",
              "libraryTarget": "umd"
            },
```

my extra-webpack.config

```
const singleSpaAngularWebpack = require('single-spa-angular/lib/webpack').default;

module.exports = (config, options) => {
  const singleSpaWebpackConfig = singleSpaAngularWebpack(config, options);
  return singleSpaWebpackConfig;
};
```

when i using extra-webpack.config will transfer less to js
if i dont retrun singleSpaWebpackConfig , will transfer to css
and i try add loader but not work
how can i using extra-webpack.config and fix it

when i deploy i need export css files not a js files